# Creating a Web Crawler using Windows Azure

Tags: azure, web-crawler, azure-worker-roles

I want to create a Web Crawler, that takes the content of some website and saves it in a blob storage. What is the right way to do that on Azure? Should I start a Worker role, and use the Thread.Sleep method to make it run once a day?

I also wonder, if I use this Worker Role, how would it work if I create two instances of it? I noticed using "Compute Emulator UI" that the command "Trace.WriteLine" works on both instances at the same time, can someone clarify this point.

I created the same crawler using php and set the cron job to start the script once a day, but it took 6 hours to grab the whole content, thats why I want to use Azure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the right way to do it, as of Jan 2014 Microsoft introduced Azure WebJobs, where you can create a project (console for example), and run it as a scheduled task (occurrence once, recurrence)

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingWindowsAzureWebJobs.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Considering that a worker role is basically Windows 2008 Server, you can run the same code you'd run on-premises.

Consider, though, that there are several reasons why a role instance might reboot: OS updates, crash, etc. In these cases, it's possible you'd lose the work being done. So... you can handle this in a few ways:

- Queue. Place a message on a command queue. If it's a once-a-day task, you can just push the message on the queue when done processing the previous message. Note that you can put an invisibility timeout on the message, so it doesn't appear for a day. In the event of failure during processing, the message will re-appear on the queue and a different instance can pick it up. You can also modify the message as you go, to keep track of your status.
- Scheduler. Just make sure there's only one instance running (by way of a mutex). An easy way to do this is to attempt to obtain a write-lock on a blob (there can only be one).

One thing to consider is breaking up your web-crawl into separate tasks (url's?) and place those individually on the queue? With this, you'd be able to scale, running either multiple instances or, potentially, multiple threads in the same instance (since web-crawling is likely to be a blocking operation, rather than a cpu- and bandwidth-intensive one).

Answer (score 0):

A single worker role running once a day is probably the best approach. I would not use thread sleep though, since you may want to restart the instance and then it may, depening on your programming, start before one day or later than one day. What about putting the task command as a message on the Azure Queue and dequeuing it once it has been picked up by a worker role, then adding a new task command on the Azure Queue once.